# Изменить локализацию для одной страницы

Tags: django

Весь сайт русский, все русифицируется с помощью локали русской, но вот одна страница мне нужна чтобы не русифицировалось.

То есть, есть фильтр `|date:"r"`, переводит на русский сам - **Птн, 27 Янв 2012 00:00:00 +0200**

Как сделать так, чтобы на этой странице он не переводил, или чтобы только этот фильтр не переводил. В общем, добиться того чтобы понедельник и январь были на английском.

Answer (score 1):

[set_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#django.views.i18n.set_language)

Comment: По этому руководству не вышло. Добавился ручной выбор языковой схемы на странице, однако у меня страница генерится для робота, а он изменять схему не будет. Сделал как раньше, самостоятельно преобразовал через фильтр. Спасибо за подсказку, думаю подобное еще пригодиться.

Comment: тогда [activate()](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/1.3.X/ref/utils.html#django.utils.translation.activate)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать временную смену локали: [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1428/)

Comment: Чет с ходу не въехал. Как сделал ниже написал.